# Calling one python script from another issue with subprocess.call()

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have following problem with running a `python` script within another `python` script by using

```
subprocess.call(["python.exe", "secondScript.py"])
```

This code works perfectly when running from `PyScripter`. But when runs from the `shell`, it does not work. Where is the problem??? I get error message

```
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

Please, could someone help! Tnx,

Comment: Try specifying full paths to `python` and `secondScript.py`

Comment: Both proposed solutions do not work unfortunately. Victor, your proposal executed crashed python shell, thus I didn't see what was the error after it :(

Comment: script2 within scrip1 works separately as well as together from PyScripter.

Comment: @ViktorKerkez yes, It works! omg, what could it be ..